# Updating schedules for jenkins jobs using groovy scripts

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to update the schedules for all the jobs in a view using groovy scripts.

I have seen these on wiki :
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clone+all+projects+in+a+View
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=42470313

Which tells how you can get all the projects in a view and update the JVM options for the maven projects. This works for **FREESTYLE** project but I wanted to if the same can be done for the project of the type **MavenModuleSet**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def newview = Hudson.instance.getView("view-name")

def newtime= "H 10 * * *"

for(item in newview.getItems())
{
 AbstractProject job= item
 for(trigger in item.triggers.values()) {
        if(trigger instanceof TimerTrigger) {
            println("--- Timer trigger for " + item.name + " ---")
            println(trigger.spec + '\n')
          TimerTrigger tt= new TimerTrigger(newtime)
          job.addTrigger(tt)
          job.save()
        }
    }

}
```